# Landsat images not showing water bodies and it appears on Google Earth

Tags: classification, landsat, resolution

I tried working with Landsat images on ArcMap 10.2 for Land Use/Land Cover changes to monitor change detection over 40 years using supervised classification. The land use is classified into four which are Vegetation, Bare Lands, Built Up Area and Water bodies but  I couldn't detect water bodies or any wetlands after processing the Landsat images. But when I checked the area on Google Earth I noticed there is a tiny river that is not on all the satellite images.

What can I do to solve this problem or is there any citation backing up satellite images of resolution 30m not picking up wetlands or waterbodies?

I need to explain the reason why the satellite is not picking the river because I am working on my masters degree project.

Comment: Please add more info on your current process and what software you are using.

Comment: It should be obvious why 30m imagery cannot identify 3-5m wide objects. You should probably be asking your advisor about the impact to your research. Note that ArcMap 10.2 is an ancient tool, released more that nine years ago, and has been is "Retired" support status for over three years.

Comment: @Vince Pls what do you suggest i can do to identify 3-5m wide objects

Comment: Ummm, 1-2m imagery, or a 1m DEM/DTM?

Comment: @Vince Thank you. i was able to use Google Earth image to solve my problem